# How to extract only the needed data from the xml format as below using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

```
<TabularResult>
    <TableMetaData>
        <ColumnName Type="dateTime">Time Description</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName Type="float">Test Data1</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName Type="float">Test Data2</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName Type="float">Test Data3</ColumnName>
    </TableMetaData>
    <Row>
        <value>14-01-2020 10:00</value>
        <value>25</value>
        <value>35</value>
        <value>45</value>
    </Row>
</TabularResult>
```

Bit Confused in parsing xml response with metadata and then row values in a nead to create chart using Extjs with only Time Description in x axis and Test Data2, Test Data3 in y axis.

Need to parse the required data alone using Javascript can anyone guide here?

Answer (score 0):

In this example you can put your XML code and pass it to javascript and parse it in the needed position.

Hope it helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<TabularResult>"+
    "<TableMetaData>"+
        "<ColumnName Type='dateTime'>Time Description</ColumnName>"+
        "<ColumnName Type='float'>Test Data1</ColumnName>"+
        "<ColumnName Type='float'>Test Data2</ColumnName>"+
        "<ColumnName Type='float'>Test Data3</ColumnName>"+
   " </TableMetaData>"+
    "<Row>"+
        "<value>14-01-2020 10:00</value>"+
       " <value>25</value>"+
        "<value>35</value>"+
       " <value>45</value>"+
   " </Row>"+
"</TabularResult>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ColumnName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! answers like this that are all code are usually avoided here, It would be helpful if you could add some extra details on how this solves the problem and/or why it works

Comment: @schu34 you are the most welcome and i try to give some example how can i pass the xml code to javascript and parse it in the favored position and always i try to do my best i am a little new here.